# Lua - convert .txt list of items into a table to then iterate through

Tags: lua

I have a long system generate list of codes (in a text.txt file) that I can’t work out how to convert them all into a suitable structure that I can then iterate through line by line.

```
Power
0000 0070 0000 0032 0080 0040 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0030 0010 0030 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0030 0010 0030 0010 0ACD

Power$1
0000 006C 0022 0002 015B 00AD 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 05F7 015B 0057 0016 0E6C

Power$2
0000 0068 0000 0022 0169 00B4 0017 0044 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0017 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0044 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0636

Etc.
```

I ideally need to achieve the following sequence.

1. read/record the name of the command (write it to a log/another txt file),
2. transmit the corresponding code, (update log/txt to show it’s been sent)
3. wait short time,
4. move on to the next one in the list.

Comment: To split your file into lines: `for line in io.lines"text.txt" do (do something with the current line) end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for all the help, I’ve used the example provided and tailored it to my specific needs..

```
local lfs = require "lfs"
local read_file_path = "/mnt/nas/vera/text1.txt" -- # path to your file here
local write_file_path = "/mnt/nas/vera/text2.txt" -- # path to your file here
local pattern1 = "^.*Power.*$" -- # your pattern to find
local pattern2 = "^.*0000.*$" -- # your pattern to find

local logFile = io.open(write_file_path, 'w')
local logs = {} -- We will use this to log the messages to log.txt later 

local i = 1;for line in io.lines(read_file_path) do
if (line:find(pattern1) or not line:find('%A')) and line:len() > 1 then
    local powerref = line
    logs[#logs+ 1] = 'Command: ' .. powerref
    elseif line:find(pattern2) then
      local ircode = line
      local x = 1 do
        print('Command ' .. x .. ' is "' .. ircode .. '" found on line ' .. i)
        x = x + 1
      local pause = os.clock()
      repeat until os.clock() > pause + 1
  end
         logs[#logs + 1] = 'Sequence: ' .. line
  end; i = i + 1 -- Raise the line number
end

logFile:write(table.concat(logs, '\n'))
logFile:flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work out that with the following functions:

`io.lines('text.txt')`: Returns an iterator function that allows you to read every line of the file.

`io.open('log.txt', 'w'):write(content)`: allows you to quickly write to a file (composed of `io.open` which returns you a file handle, and `file:write`).

`io.flush()`: *flushes* the stream. If the stream has saved any characters from write(), write them immediately to their intended destination (save the file).

`string.find(pattern)`: using the pattern provided, returns the position of the substrings found.

`string.len()`: returns the length of the string, in the example I used it to verify it was not a blank line.

`table.concat(table, delimiter)`: returns a string containing all the elements of a table jointed together, separated by the delimiter specified as a second argument.

If you really need to make a pause, use `os.clock()` which returns an approximation of the amount in seconds of CPU time used by the program.

Something like this should work for you:

```
local logFile = io.open('log.txt', 'w')
local logs = {} -- We will use this to log the messages to log.txt later 

local i = 1;for line in io.lines("text.txt") do
  -- %d represents digits, %A represents all non-letter characters this translates to: "if the line contains "$x" or only contains letters"
  if (line:find('$%d') or not line:find('%A')) and line:len() > 1 then
    logs[#logs+ 1] = 'Command: ' .. line
  elseif line:find('%d') then
    -- This will run if the sequence does not contain $x or only contains letters (such as Power$1 or Power)
    
    -- If you want to iterate through every single instruction, you can use %S+ to separate by whitespaces
    local x = 1;for instruction in line:gmatch('%S+') do
      print('Instruction ' .. x .. ' at line ' .. i, instruction)
      x = x + 1

      -- Wait 1 second (this allows you to read the current instruction but makes it slower)
      local pause = os.clock()
      repeat until os.clock() > pause + 1
    end

    -- If you want to write it during the loop use logFile:write(content); logFile:flush(),
    -- otherwise append it to logs[#logs + 1] and write it when the program is finished using table.concat()
    
    logs[#logs + 1] = 'Sequence: ' .. line

    
  end; i = i + 1 -- Raise the line number
end

-- Concatenate the information and save it to logs file

logFile:write(table.concat(logs, '\n'))
logFile:flush()
```

This generated the following output to log.txt:

```
Command: Power
Sequence: 0000 0070 0000 0032 0080 0040 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0030 0010 0030 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0030 0010 0030 0010 0ACD
Command: Power$1
Sequence: 0000 006C 0022 0002 015B 00AD 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 05F7 015B 0057 0016 0E6C
Command: Power$2
Sequence: 0000 0068 0000 0022 0169 00B4 0017 0044 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0017 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0044 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0017 0017 0044 0017 0044 0017 0017 0017 0636
```

And prints the following to console:

```
Instruction 1 at line 3 0000
Instruction 2 at line 3 0070
Instruction 3 at line 3 0000
Instruction 4 at line 3 0032
Instruction 5 at line 3 0080
Instruction 6 at line 3 0040
Instruction 7 at line 3 0010
Instruction 8 at line 3 0010
Instruction 9 at line 3 0010
. . .
```

Comment: Many thanks, sadly the above didn’t quite work. The print out got to line 109 and then started again and then got to 96 and then started again, and then 102 and so on, it just kept going. And as it seemed to continually iterates through the file - it eventually forced a crash/re-load of Lua . Also each ‘sequence’ was written multiple times to the log file. under its ‘power ref. There are 120 power commands in the text file if that helps - is there a way for it to just iterate/go through the text.1 the once ?

Comment: I think the line/area that needs correcting is local x = 1;for instruction in line:gmatch('%S+') do , I’ve tried it with ($x) and also with just the first part x=1

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer, the  command i need to send/test is the whole string Power = 
0000 0070 0000 0032 0080 0040 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0030 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0030 0010 0010 0010 0030 0010 0030 0010 0030 0010 0ACD
) not each 4 digits